# Function undefined error but no error causing this

Tags: javascript, html

I have tested the following JavaScript in the Chrome and Edge dev consoles a lot of times, and it says all functions are undefined. It does not tell me what the cause of this is, though. Here is the code (I think the error may be in toggleMenu as I just added this). The webstie is tactiletimes.org. I have also tried putting const before list but this just brings up an unexpected identifyer error

````
list = "<ul><li><a href="about">About Us</a></li><li><a href="subscribe">Subscribe for free</a></li><li><a href="issues.html">Issue Archive</a></li><li><a href="contribute">Contribute to Issue 4</a></li><li><a href="contact">Contact us</a></li><li><a href="#menu">View full menu</a></li></ul>";
  
  function clearCookies(){
    deleteAllCookies();
    document.getElementById("cookieButton").innerHTML = "Successfully cleared data"+document.cookie
  }

  function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0){ return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length)};
    }
    return null;
}
  
  function deleteAllCookies(){
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}

function changeBodyColor(color){
  document.cookie = "bgColor="+color;
  document.getElementById("footer").style.color = "yellow";  
  changeLinkColor("yellow")
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  if (color == "white"){
    document.body.style.color = "black";
    changeLinkColor("blue");
  }
  else if (color == "black"){
    document.body.style.color = "white";
  }
  else if (color == "yellow"){
    document.body.style.color = "black";
    changeLinkColor("blue");
    document.getElementById("footer").style.color = "red";
  }
  else if (color == "purple"){
    document.body.style.color = "white";  
  }
  else if (color == "blue"){
    document.body.style.color = "white";
    }
    else if (color == "green"){
    document.body.style.color = "black";  
  changeLinkColor("blue");
  document.getElementById("footer").style.color = "red";  
  }
  else if (color == "orange"){
    changeLinkColor("blue");
  }
  
  
}

function changeLinkColor(color){
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    links[i].style.color = color;
  }
  
  
}

function restoreBgColor(){
  if (!readCookie("bgColor") == null){
    changeBodyColor(readCookie(bgColor));
  }
}

function toggleMenu(){
  if (document.getElementById("topmenu").innerHTML != ""){
    document.getElementById("topmenu").innerHTML = "";
  }
else{
  document.getElementById("topmenu").innerHTML = list;
}
}

</script> ```
````

Comment: I do not know why the <script> tag did not get added to this questionbut I did add it to miy code

Comment: list is breaking the code because of the wrong usage of double codes. Fix it first, then let me know if you will get the same error.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have solved the problem. I am just wondering why double quotes are not allowed in this situation as another question about double and single quotes make it look as they were used in the same situations (like in Python)

Comment: Because "<ul><li><a href=" is a complete string, everyting after that is something else.

Answer (score 0):

I went to tactiletimes.org to see the bug in action.

This line did it:

```
list = '<ul><li><a href="about">About Us</a></li><li><a href="subscribe">Subscribe for free</a></li><li><a href="issues.html">Issue Archive</a></li><li><a href="contribute">Contribute to Issue 4</a></li><li><a href="contact">Contact us</a></li><li><a href="#menu">View full menu</a></li></ul>'';
```

Just remove the last single quote (which has no use), and it works.

```
var list = '<ul><li><a href="about">About Us</a></li><li><a href="subscribe">Subscribe for free</a></li><li><a href="issues.html">Issue Archive</a></li><li><a href="contribute">Contribute to Issue 4</a></li><li><a href="contact">Contact us</a></li><li><a href="#menu">View full menu</a></li></ul>';
```

Now you know why you had the issue after redoing your qoutes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `list` variable. I just replaced the outer `"` with a `'`

```js
list = '<ul><li><a href="about">About Us</a></li><li><a href="subscribe">Subscribe for free</a></li><li><a href="issues.html">Issue Archive</a></li><li><a href="contribute">Contribute to Issue 4</a></li><li><a href="contact">Contact us</a></li><li><a href="#menu">View full menu</a></li></ul>';

function clearCookies() {
  deleteAllCookies();
  document.getElementById("cookieButton").innerHTML = "Successfully cleared data" + document.cookie
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
      return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length)
    };
  }
  return null;
}

function deleteAllCookies() {
  var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

  for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    var cookie = cookies[i];
    var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
    var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
    document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
  }
}

function changeBodyColor(color) {
  document.cookie = "bgColor=" + color;
  document.getElementById("footer").style.color = "yellow";
  changeLinkColor("yellow")
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  if (color == "white") {
    document.body.style.color = "black";
    changeLinkColor("blue");
  } else if (color == "black") {
    document.body.style.color = "white";
  } else if (color == "yellow") {
    document.body.style.color = "black";
    changeLinkColor("blue");
    document.getElementById("footer").style.color = "red";
  } else if (color == "purple") {
    document.body.style.color = "white";
  } else if (color == "blue") {
    document.body.style.color = "white";
  } else if (color == "green") {
    document.body.style.color = "black";
    changeLinkColor("blue");
    document.getElementById("footer").style.color = "red";
  } else if (color == "orange") {
    changeLinkColor("blue");
  }
}

function changeLinkColor(color) {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].style.color = color;
  }
}

function restoreBgColor() {
  if (!readCookie("bgColor") == null) {
    changeBodyColor(readCookie(bgColor));
  }
}

function toggleMenu() {
  if (document.getElementById("topmenu").innerHTML != "") {
    document.getElementById("topmenu").innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("topmenu").innerHTML = list;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your quotes in the first line and remove the three backticks at the end.

```
<script>
var list = '<ul><li><a href="about">About Us</a></li><li><a href="subscribe">Subscribe for free</a></li><li><a href="issues.html">Issue Archive</a></li><li><a href="contribute">Contribute to Issue 4</a></li><li><a href="contact">Contact us</a></li><li><a href="#menu">View full menu</a></li></ul>';

function clearCookies(){
    deleteAllCookies();
    document.getElementById("cookieButton").innerHTML = "Successfully cleared data"+document.cookie
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0){ return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length)};
    }
    return null;
}

function deleteAllCookies(){
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}

function changeBodyColor(color){
    document.cookie = "bgColor="+color;
    document.getElementById("footer").style.color = "yellow";  
    changeLinkColor("yellow")
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    if (color == "white"){
        document.body.style.color = "black";
        changeLinkColor("blue");
    }
    else if (color == "black"){
        document.body.style.color = "white";
    }
    else if (color == "yellow"){
        document.body.style.color = "black";
        changeLinkColor("blue");
        document.getElementById("footer").style.color = "red";
    }
    else if (color == "purple"){
        document.body.style.color = "white";  
    }
    else if (color == "blue"){
        document.body.style.color = "white";
    }
    else if (color == "green"){
        document.body.style.color = "black";  
        changeLinkColor("blue");
        document.getElementById("footer").style.color = "red";  
    }
    else if (color == "orange"){
        changeLinkColor("blue");
    }
    
    
}

function changeLinkColor(color){
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
        links[i].style.color = color;
    }
    
    
}

function restoreBgColor(){
    if (!readCookie("bgColor") == null){
        changeBodyColor(readCookie(bgColor));
    }
}

function toggleMenu(){
    if (document.getElementById("topmenu").innerHTML != ""){
        document.getElementById("topmenu").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("topmenu").innerHTML = list;
    }
}
</script>
```